# Get column stats in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to determine two things in a SQL Server 2008 database.

First, I need to know the columns that have null values in them.

Second, I need to know the count of nulls per column in the actual tables.

I know I can get the first one by doing:

```
SELECT t.name, c.name 
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE c.is_nullable = 1
```

I am struggling to find the second part though.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table `atable` with columns `not_nullable` and `is_nullable`. As count does not count anything - you could instead count only where the columns is null

```
SELECT count(*) count_nulls FROM atable WHERE is_nullable is null;
```

Now how to do that for all nullable columns?

I came up with this - but its veeeery slow. But then again - how often do you need to do that?

```
create table #nullcolumns(nullable_column varchar(255), count_nulls int);

declare @sqladd nvarchar(1000);

DECLARE users_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT /* TOP 20 */  'INSERT INTO #nullcolumns SELECT '''+
 t.name+'.'+c.name+''' as nullable_column, count(*) from '
      +t.name+' WHERE '+c.name+' IS NULL '
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE c.is_nullable = 1 

OPEN users_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor
INTO @sqladd

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

exec sp_executesql @sqladd;
print @sqladd;


FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor 
INTO @sqladd

END
CLOSE users_cursor
DEALLOCATE users_cursor

SELECT * FROM #nullcolumns;
```